# XSLT parsing XML to generate Word document

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, ms-word

I have an XLST file that is supposed to parse an XML file and generate Word document. But when I parse it in Visual Studio it produces another XML because its header is:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
        <xsl:text>progid="Word.Document"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
```

I tried the method= "text" but it generates a plain text with no formatting.
what property should I specify so that when I run the transformation it saves the result in a Word document?

Comment: .docx word documents are XML documents, albeit zipped, from what I remember. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Comment: What kind of format do you want to generate for Word? Word understands about 20 different formats or even more.

Comment: a standart .doc document

Comment: You won't be able to create a *binary* .doc Word document using XSLT. What you can do is to use the Word 2003 XML format which is an XML file with a .xml file extension. Actually your sample already looks a lot like this format. This works fine and I assume your question is just based on that misunderstanding.

Comment: @OxA3 thanks, i figured that out. you can write your comment as an answer if you want so i can choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option might be to simply generate HTML (and specify the output method as HTML) and save the file with a .doc extension.

MS Word will open the file without complaining (though it still knows that it's a web page)